# Linux Huge pages memory usage calculation

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, linux-kernel, huge-pages

I read [the article](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/UNXAR/appi_vlm.htm#UNXAR391) about Linux Huge pages technology and misunderstood some important detail.
Here is the phrase:

> For example, if you use HugePages with 64-bit hardware, and you want
> to map 256 MB of memory, you may need one page table entry (PTE). If
> you do not use HugePages, and you want to map 256 MB of memory, then
> you must have 256 MB * 1024 KB/4 KB = 65536 PTEs.

I don't understand what is `1024 KB` in this formula. I think it should be just `256 MB / 4 KB` to calculate the number of table entries. Is there a typo in formula or am I wrong?

Comment: What they mean is to convert MB into KB, that's why *1024. The formula they've written is awkward and confusing because of erroneous using of units labels.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it is confusing. After reading it several times, I believe that it is as simple as a matter of unit conversion. At school the mathematics/physics/chemistry teachers always told us to use the same units when doing operations in order to obtain coherent results.

The value 256 is expressed in megabytes (MB). To divide it by 4 expressed in kilo-bytes (KB), you need to convert it into kilo-bytes. Hence, the multiplication by 1024KB (= 1MB). So, literally the operation is: (256 x 1024) / 4 = 65536 which is the simplification of: (256 x 1024 x 1024) / (4 x 1024)